# How to start and monitor a set of programs in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, process, wait

I use a system that is started by a script similar to that:

```
#!/bin/bash

prog_a &     # run continuously
prog_b &     # run continuously
prog_c &     # run continuously

sleep 2      # wait for some stuff to be done

prog_d       # start 'main' program ...

killall -9 prog_a
killall -9 prog_b
killall -9 prog_c
```

It works well. If I do a *ctrl-c* in the terminal (or if prog_d crashes), then prog_d died and the first processes prog_a, prog_b, prog_c are killed.

The problem I have is that *sometimes* prog_a, prog_b or prog_c crashed. And prog_d is still alive. What I would like in fact is: if one program died, then the other ones are killed.

Is it possible to do that simply in bash ? I have tried to create a kind of:

```
wait pid1 pid2 pid3 ... # wait that pid1 or pid2 or pid3 died
```

But without success (I need to be able to do a ctrl-c to kill prog_d).

Thanks !

Comment: `killall -9` has no place in a program on a production system.

Comment: How is it supposed to work? In simple English. You want programs A, B and C to run for at least 2 seconds and then you want program D to run. As soon as program D finishes, or is killed A, B and C should stop?

Comment: I want programs A, B, C and D run continuously (I should have mention this). A, B, C are started with '&'. As A, B, C setup things needed by D, that is why there is a 'sleep'.


I want to a stop all programs if one program failed. Note: it is not for production. I have no access to A, B, C, D code.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with **GNU Parallel**, which has nice handling for what to do when any job fails... whether one or more or a percentage fail, whether other jobs should be terminated immediately or only no new jobs should be started.

In your specific case:

```
parallel -j 4 --halt now,fail=1 --line-buffer ::: progA progB progC 'sleep 2; progD'
```

That says... "*run all four jobs parallel, and halt immediately killing all others if any job fails. Buffer the output by lines. The jobs to be run are then specified after the `:::` and they are just your jobs but with a delay before the final one."*

You may like the output tagged by the job-name, so you can see which outputs came from which processes, if so, use `parallel --tag ...`

You may like to delay/stagger the starts of each job, in which case use `parallel --delay 1` to start jobs at 1 second intervals and remove the `sleep 2`.